# Flutter keeps crashing on debug

Tags: flutter, dart

Flutter keeps on spawning OpenJDK Platform binary instances until my PC runs out of memory and crashing giving me an out of memory error. I have 16 gigs of RAM which should be more than enough but for some reason, all 16 gigs are used once I run `flutter run`.
I have also run `flutter clean`, `flutter upgrade`, `flutter pub upgrade` and even updated android studio and flutter itself but the problem persists.

Here is the output from the debug console:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Redmi Y2 in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the User Manual chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/6.7/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Process command line: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java.exe --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.prefs/java.util.prefs=ALL-UNNAMED -Xmx1536M -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -Duser.country=IN -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -cp C:\Users\NIC-PC1\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-6.7-all\cuy9mc7upwgwgeb72wkcrupxe\gradle-6.7\lib\gradle-launcher-6.7.jar org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 6.7
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00000000a0000000, 266338304, 0) failed; error='The paging file is too small for this operation to complete' (DOS error/errno=1455)
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 266338304 bytes for Failed to commit area from 0x00000000a0000000 to 0x00000000afe00000 of length 266338304.
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\NIC-PC1\.gradle\daemon\6.7\hs_err_pid2304.log


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

Any ideas? Please.

Comment: try using embedded jvm for gradle

Comment: I have these settings in `android/gradle.properties` and it works for me: `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx512M` 
`android.useAndroidX=true`
`android.enableJetifier=true`

Comment: @TeodorVladutu I've tried this. It didn't work

Comment: @p2kr how do i do that?

Comment: If using android studio: go to settings and change jdk location to https://i.stack.imgur.com/K31m4.png

Comment: It didn't work @p2kr

Comment: try re-installing jdk and another version of it. Also upgrade gradle version.

Answer (score -1):

To fix this I just uninstall both android studio and flutter.